# Transformar documento xls/xlsx a html - sin interop

Tags: c#, html, .net, excel, conversión-de-tipos

Tengo un documento `xls` y otro `xlsx` ya guardado en `bytes[]` en mi código y necesito pasarlo a `html+css` para poder mostrarlo en una página.

Es importante destacar que necesito también el `css` y eso significa que leer cada fila individualmente del excel no es una opción ya que perdería el estilo.

Estoy utilizando Visual Studio con .NET para desarrollarlo en [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23).

Actualmente ya me funciona a partir de pdf que es fácil de transformar a html pero no es el caso de `xls`, `xlsx` ni ningún producto de Microsoft ya que no puedo utilizar la librería nativa `interop` ya que no es garantía que el servidor lo tenga instalado.

El resultado sería algo parecido a esto:

```
strFinalXls = strFinalXls.Replace("<body>", "<body>" + documentInfoHtml + "<BR /><BR />");
```

Dónde `documentInfoHtml` es el resultado de transformar los `bytes[]` a html y `strFinalXls` es simplemente el contenido que reemplaza el `body` de una página.

He encontrado alguna solución pero prácticamente todas utilizan `interop` o bien librerías de pago.

¿Conocéis alguna manera de hacerlo con software libre o proyectos abiertos?

---

Es importante también mantener el máximo posible los estilos CSS existentes por lo que respuestas que simplemente extraigan el contenido para generarlo yo en `HTML` no es suficiente en el sentido de que perdería todo el formato.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A partir de la librería [NPOI](https://github.com/tonyqus/npoi/tree/master/solution/Lib) para C# (descargado del github, NO del Nuget, ya que en el Nuget faltan algunas DLL):

**Código Principal** - Importante destacar que es distinto un XLS que un XLSX (está marcado en el código)

```
Stream stream = new MemoryStream(document.Fichero); //document.Fichero son los byte[] puros del XLS/XLSX
Stream stream2 = new MemoryStream();
stream.Position = 0;
ExcelToHtmlConverter excelToHtmlConverter = new ExcelToHtmlConverter();
excelToHtmlConverter.OutputColumnHeaders = false;
excelToHtmlConverter.OutputHiddenColumns = true;
excelToHtmlConverter.OutputHiddenRows = true;
excelToHtmlConverter.OutputLeadingSpacesAsNonBreaking = false;
excelToHtmlConverter.OutputRowNumbers = true;
excelToHtmlConverter.UseDivsToSpan = true;

if (document.Extension.ToUpper() == "XLSX")
{
    //XLSX
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(stream);
    excelToHtmlConverter.ProcessWorkbook(workbook);
}
else
{
    //XLS
    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(stream);
    excelToHtmlConverter.ProcessWorkbook(workbook);
}

excelToHtmlConverter.Document.Save(stream2);
stream2.Position = 0;
var mmmm = ReadFully(stream2);
var msAux2 = ConvertDocumentToHtmlMemoryStream(mmmm, "");
var documentInfoHtml = BytesToStringConverted(msAux2.ToArray());
```

Faltan definir las funciones `ReadFully`, `ConvertDocumentToHtmlMemoryStream` y `BytesToStringConverted`:

**ReadFully** - Transforma un `Stream` a `byte[]`:

```
public static byte[] ReadFully(Stream input)
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        input.CopyTo(ms);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

**ConvertDocumentToHtmlMemoryStream** - Añade información para su generación a HTML

```
private MemoryStream ConvertDocumentToHtmlMemoryStream(byte[] document, string documentInfoHtml)
{
    byte[] result = null;

    //Documento
    var strBuilder = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    foreach (var b in document)
    {
        strBuilder.Append((char)b);
    }
    var strFinalDoc = strBuilder.ToString();
    strFinalDoc = strFinalDoc.Replace("<a href=", "<br /><a href=");
    strFinalDoc = strFinalDoc.Replace("</a>", "</a><br />");

    //Información
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(documentInfoHtml))
    {
        strFinalDoc = strFinalDoc.Replace("<body>", "<body>" + documentInfoHtml + "<BR /><BR />");
    }

    //Imprimir
    if (Action.ToLower() == Enumerators.ActionType.Print.ToString().ToLower())
    {
        var strImprime = "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>";
        strImprime += "     window.print();";
        strImprime += "</script>";
        strImprime += "</html>";

        strFinalDoc = strFinalDoc.Replace("</html>", strImprime);
    }

    var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(strFinalDoc);
    if (bytes.Length > 0)
    {
        return new MemoryStream(bytes);
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**BytesToStringConverted** - Transforma de `byte[]` a `string`

```
static string BytesToStringConverted(byte[] bytes)
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
    {
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```